# Jquery append/Remove and saving to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I was wondering if anyone could take a look at this code and help me come up with a better way to do this if there is one.

I am using jQuery append/remove to add and remove list items. My code first selects any existing rows from the db and displays those in the list, and then the user can add or remove any elements from the list.

I have a database structure similar to this:

```
object_id  element_id   auto   order
   1          1          0       2
   1          2          0       1
   1          3          1       3
```

After users have finished appending/remove I will be left with html code similar to this:

```
<ul id="element-list" class="ui-sortable"><li>
<label for="element">Element Description</label>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="element[1][id]">
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="element[1][auto]">
</li>

<li>
<label for="element">Element Description</label>
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="element[2][id]">
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="element[2][auto]">
</li>
</ul>
```

As users can add and remove elements including rows which exist in the database I am puzzled about how it is best to save these changes in the database. Currently I am deleting all corresponding rows then inserting new rows inside a loop as follows:

```
foreach($_POST['element'] as $element){

$auto = (isset($element["auto"])) ? 1 : 0;

$query="INSERT INTO $table (object_id, element_id, auto) VALUES ('".$object_id."', '".$element["id"]."', '".$auto."') ";
}
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this than deleting all rows then inserting new ones?

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Is this some kind of EAV schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely the easiest way to do it.

2 suggestions...

1. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with prepared queries. Your code is vulnerable to sql injection.
2. Use [transactions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php). It would suck if you deleted all the rows and then somethign happened and the new rows werent inserted. This way you can [rollback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php) if the insertions arent completed.

Comment: Thanks for your input I will look into your suggestions too

Comment: In my opinion, rollback is a horrible idea.  Ensure your code is bug free before you go live and avoid using rollback.  It's more memory/processing that isn't needed if all of your code works correctly.

Comment: @webnet - rollback has to do with more than code. servers can go down, networks can go down. rollbacks arent for bad code.

Comment: Rollback undoes what the previous query just did, right?  If that's the case, the only time I can imagine with my limited experience is that if you need to rollback then your code was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting all rows and inserting new ones is the best method to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.  However, if you want to optimize your code, change your SQL so that you're doing all your inserts in a single query...

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
 (val1, val2, val3),
 (val1, val2, val3),
 (val1, val2, val3),
 (val1, val2, val3),
 (val1, val2, val3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting rows before updating is good if your new rows count is other.